# How to run 2 different processes with python at the same time?

Tags: python, performance, multiprocessing

I have a looping script , to get infos on a french site. It looks like this :

```
def getInfos(a,b,c)

def MyLoop(filename)
```

in which i call getinfos via

```
def MyLoop(filename) 
    values = getInfos()
```

And It works well. But sometimes, the script slows down and finally stops. 
So i tried several modules with different ideas in mind.
The first module ; Signal. But (subjectively) interesting functions are not avalaible on windows.
However, i tried to stimulate execution when it's frozen:

```
def reboot(signal, frame):
    print '??FROZEN??'
    time.sleep(1)
    #sys.exit(0)
signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, reboot)
```

As you can see i tried `sys.exit(0)`, but too abrupt, and i'm not sur of what's really done. Anyway... after a two-hour loop, i get no answer with this transformed "`keyboard interrupt`" function.

Then i tried to limit execution time.
So i found : `Multiprocessing`, `pp`, `signal (~5%avalaibleOnWindows)`.
The first one opened 30 or 40 other brackgrounded python processes.
The second one, pp, do not allow to paralelize two differents function. No it does ?

Do you have something that could work for me ? or at least, something i can try, to figure me out where the first step is ?

14 months later...
Finally, surely by lack of experience, i decided to use multiprocessing. Making some bots as executors, and 1 of them as checker/killer of the possibly frozen external process.

First, the multoprocessing approach:

```
#my_mp.py
import multiprocessing as mp
import actions as ac
bot_ids = list('ab')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    jobs = []
    for bot_id in bot_ids:
        p = mp.Process(target=ac.Act , args=(bot_id,))
        jobs.append(p)  ;  p.start()
```

Then, what is multiprocessed:

```
#actions.py
import time,random,glob,os,psutil
#________________________
def check_or_kill(eXe,bTm):
    age_max = 900
    if time.time() - bTm > age_max:
        for proc in psutil.process_iter():
            if  (proc.name == eXe):proc.kill()
    return
#________________________
def Act(bot_id):
    checker = random.choice(list('ab'))
    if bot_id not in checker:
        f = open('stTime_%s.txt'%bot_id , 'w')  ;  f.write('%s'%(time.time()))  ; f.close()
        #launch the execution file and then, when it's done :
        os.remove('stTime_%s.txt'%bot_id)
    else:
        #get their inner birthtime.
        while glob.glob('localfolder_path','stTime_*.txt') != []: check_or_kill('soft.exe',birthtime)
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

For asynchronous programming try [twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions)

Here is a good book for beginners: [Twisted Introduction](http://krondo.com/?page_id=1327)

Comment: Thank you warwaruk. But according to this "Twisted Introduction" : "Windows is a strange, murky place and, if you are hacking in it, I can’t offer you much more beyond my heartfelt sympathies."

Comment: Still, `twisted` works on Windows, regardless of this author's opinion on it :)

Answer (score 0):

Is your process getting hung on a web request?  In the standard library [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html) there is a function `urllib2.urlopen` which takes in an optional `timeout` parameter.  If that is what you are using, try setting the timeout parameter and handling the case where your request fails.

Comment: I'm too new of a user (I think?) to add comments to posts that are not mine.  I think having a better understanding of the problem you are trying to solve would be helpful.  As you've stated, `multiprocessing` would let you run multiple processes, but that's a complicated solution that might just disguise a simpler problem.  Can you post more of your code?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. No i was not using urllib2, but external processes called from my functions.